# Not sure how to set up cronjob properly to run php function

Tags: apache-2.2, php, cron

Im not sure on how I should do to set up a cronjob to run a php function for my website, and doing so by using a URL.

I dont want any output etc, I just want the cronjob to run the php function buy visiting the URL. Or getting outputs doesnt affect my server performance?

So, is the code bellow a good way to run my cronjob? In order to run my php function.

Eg running it 5Am each day.

```
* 5 * * * wget http://www.mysite.com/set/cleancreon.php?id=9876
```

and inside cleancreon.php as a id check:

```
if (isset($_GET['id']))
{
  $id = $_GET['id'];


  if (is_numeric($id))
  {
    $id = (int)$id;

    if ($id == 9876) {
        runfunction();
     } else { 
            die(); 
     }
  } else { die();  }

} else { die();  }
```

Would this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the problem you are having with this?

Comment: My problem is that I dont know if this is the right/best way to do it. I dont want to fill any logs/output up etc.

So would just calling "* 5 * * * wget http://www.mysite.com/set/cleancreon.php?id=9876" be a good way to run my cronjob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're configuration looks fine. I'm worried about the security of this page though.

If you leave this in a public location you're likely to have trouble keeping people from running it. Since wget isn't using a cookie or HTTP security you must not be logging in with it which means that you probably don't have this very well protected.

I would at a minimum start checking for the request IP but even that is really lame because it is spoofable.

It IS possible to save your cookies and let wget use those. If you want to do that then read `man wget`. This extension for Chrome may be of use to you for this as well: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookietxt-export/lopabhfecdfhgogdbojmaicoicjekelh?hl=en .

You could also use old fashion HTTP security to handle this too. The man page and the Apache website will get you through that with little trouble I'd imagine as well.

A generally better solution is to run the script directly, something like `* 5 * * * php /path/to/cleancreon.php 9876` would be a little better because (if you move it to a private folder) you wouldn't need to worry about the public accessing it at all.

To make this work you'll also need to alter the way you read your arguments as well (don't forget to sanitize\validate the input), like so:

```
$id=isset($argv[1])?$argv[1]:(isset($_GET['id']?$_GET['id']:null);
```

Whichever way you go with I would suggest that you reconsider logging this action though. If you do not log the results there is going to be no way of knowing whether it worked or not unless the php code is somehow recording that status (doesn't appear to be but perhaps runfunction() is doing something we don't see).

One final note, the code you've posted (along with my suggested fix) can be reduced to:

```
if((isset($argv[1])?$argv[1]:(isset($_GET['id'])?$_GET['id']:null))!=9876) die();
runfunction();
```

IDK about you but I hate reading all of that extra code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer krowe! But isnt it safe to give id= a long string, thats more or less impossible for people to guess (together with a strong sanitize). Eg id=45759372642..
But I will prob do as you said, just call the script from a protected file, but if I do so, I still have to include connections to my DB etc right? Eg require_once('..var/www/init/config.php'); 
Consider my app is in var/www

Comment: That isn't a very secure thing to do because requests get cached all over the place (eg routers, proxies, tracking cookies). It isn't difficult to make your script work from both the command line and a url but if you want to make it usable from a url then it either needs to be safe to run anytime or protected by  more than just a hidden variable in the url. A session variable is what you want to use. IOW, make the user log in to run the script. If you don't already have that setup on your site then it is far easier to just make it CLI; cron works best that way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cron command is valid (which is easy enough for you to check: is the php running or not?) and the only thing you need to know is how to make sure logs aren't building up anywhere, know that you can direct where all of the output is going by using `>` the same way you can redirect output from the console. `> /dev/null 2>&1` will redirect all output and errors to null.

```
* 5 * * * wget http://www.mysite.com/set/cleancreon.php?id=9876 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Of course, the proper thing to do would be to direct the errors to a logfile somewhere, or possibly have them emailed, etc.

Comment: Thanks alot, so using  > /dev/null 2>&1 wont give me any logs? I am pretty new to ubuntu and still testing my app out so I already have tons of logs to check out. And the function I am trying to run isnt that important, just helping me out a bit. But I will make sure to read about > /dev/null, cheers